# Apply SlideTransition effect to a TextBlock in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I would like to apply a SlideTransition effect to a TextBlock similar to the title of the Calendar app which changes when scrolling down or up through the days (starting from "TODAY").

The following code reported [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wfaught/archive/2010/11/15/transitions.aspx) is a good starting point:

```
SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition { Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideUpFadeIn };
ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(ApplicationTitle);
transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); };
transition.Begin();
```

but I'd like to declare it in XAML rather than developing in C#.

is it possible?

thank you,

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not declare UIElement Transition in XAML. You can declare in XAML only Page Transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Is it *possible*? probably.  almost anything is possible.

You're probably going to have to write your own attached property/event or behavior that wraps that code, and then wire that up into your xaml